# routing through wireguard tunnel interface on client host

Tags: vpn, routing, tunnel, wireguard

I'd like to use wireguard as my VPN solution. I use mullvad, so I can use their servers and keys for configuration. After I do `sudo wg-quick up wg0`, I connect:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: <client public key>
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 52065
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer: <peer public key>
  endpoint: <EndpointIPaddr>:51820
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
  latest handshake: 20 minutes, 38 seconds ago
  transfer: 92 B received, 186.51 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 30 seconds
```

But this didn't change the routing table, so I modified it like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         128.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 wg0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlp1s0
128.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         128.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 wg0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wg0
<EndpointIPaddr>  192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
```

(Before, this table had only 2nd, 4th and the last line.) However, I still cannot route my traffic through the tunnel. `ifconfig wg0` returns:

```
wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.69.136.236  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.69.136.236
        inet6 fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::6:88eb  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 1  bytes 92 (92.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 306  bytes 62724 (62.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I think this is about forwarding, but I don't know how to approach to it. I've `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` set to 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting mullvad support it turned out this was about isp blocking. On different network I can connect using mullvad application. For anyone curious, this is what my routing table looks like for successful connection (openvpn):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.5.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp1s0
10.5.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun0
127.0.0.1       192.168.43.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp1s0
128.0.0.0       10.5.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
<EndpointIP>   192.168.43.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp1s0
```

And here is `ifconfig tun0`:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.5.0.7  netmask 255.255.0.0  destination 10.5.0.7
        inet6 fe80::63:ff47:e1da:9c17  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 29314  bytes 24238191 (24.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19736  bytes 3829452 (3.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```